# TFS VNext build Delete Files task need to exclude one file

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I need to use the delete files task in a VNext build definition (TFS 2015).
asp.net c# web app on an IIS 7.5.
I found that we can use exclusion pattern, but it's not working.
How can I make this work?
Delete all files except app_offline.htm.
**;-:app_offline.htm

If it can't work like that, how can I make sure that the users will get the app_offline.htm file even when I'm deploying the application.

I first created a build to copy the app_offline page and another build to delete it. My problem is in the middle.
thanks

Comment: Try to add [-enableRule:AppOffline parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing).

Comment: I can't use your setting because the tfs build is compiling the solution. I tried /p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true that is supposed to do the same thing, but there is no app_offline.htm file generated at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a site hosted in IIS online but showing a maintenance page is less than ideal. Since it's still processing the application's web.config, users will get intermittent errors during the deployment, depending on what files are currently changing and whether IIS is able to load the assemblies referenced in the web.config.

A better approach is to deploy a static maintenance page to a separate web site.

Then your deployment process can just be:

- Stop real site
- Start maintenance site
- Deploy real site
- Stop maintenance site
- Start real site

Assuming the two sites have the same bindings, users will seamlessly be redirected to the maintenance site for the duration of the deployment.

Dealing with a site that's load balanced across multiple web servers is a slightly different scenario with additional options and considerations, but I'm assuming that's not the case here.

Comment: I need a way to do this without touching IIS. Using TFS VNext Build.

Comment: @CaptainKirk Try to use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp